# Java program returning int array with 3 elements (#of lines, # of words, # of characters) from a text fil

Tags: java, character, lines, words, wc

My code is using the read() function to "read" through a txt file one character at a time and needs to internally count the number of lines, words, and characters.

Definitions of what is considered a line, word, and character:

## of characters = any character that is "read" even if it is a 'whitespace' character

## of lines = whenever the whitespace character '\n' is read.

## of words = whenever a non-whitespace character is read that is either the first word OR one that is preceded by a whitespace character

*** I used Character.isWhitespace() method to determine if the current character is a whitespace or not.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class UnixCommands{
     public int[] wc(Reader in) throws IOException {
         int[] result = new int[3]; 
         int countChar = 0;
         int countWord = 0; 
         int countLine = 0;
         int savedD = -1;
         int data = in.read(); 

        while (data != -1) {  
            countChar++; //countChar no matter what.
            if(data == '\n') { //countLine if '\n' is read.
            countLine++;
            } 
            if((countWord == 0 && !Character.isWhitespace(data)) || 
            // first word appears
          (!Character.isWhitespace(data) && Character.isWhitespace(savedD))) 
            //anytime another word appear.
        {
            countWord++;
        } 

        savedD = data;
        data = in.read();
    }  
        result[0] = countLine;
        result[1] = countWord;
        result[2] = countChar;
        System.out.println(countLine);
        System.out.println(countWord);
        System.out.println(countChar);
        System.out.println(result);

    return result;
 }
```

}

```
Input: I am giving it a text file.
Output: 
63852     -> count of lines
562492    -> count of words (i think my number of words is off by 1 word) 
3202326    -> count of characters
[I@63b719   -> not sure why my result array is outputting this
```

I guess the question is why is not outputting the appropriate number of words?

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove this line

```
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: No I believe i have not encompassed all possible edge cases, in my "while" statement"

So the output for number of lines, words and characters is incorrect.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to pin-point the exact "word" that causes the wrong count. It could be a special character.